# Java Android call requires permission which may be rejected by user

Tags: java, android

When I call the getLastKnownLocation () method I get an error "Java Android call requires permission which may be rejected by user...". Apparently it's due to API23.
I can't find a valid solution yet.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: search for `android runtime permissions`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` to check if you need to show the reason why you need this permission (and if it returns true - show the reason), and, of course, you need to request permissions with `requestPermissions()` method.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't do anything if user rejected the permission. It is meant to give error if user reject the request. You can do one thing if user deny then give a dialog to user asking to accept it otherwise the functionality will not work and redirect him to that permission dialog.